# No Such Element Exception (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a weird issue while testing a web application through Selenium.

There is an `add new` feature in my application. I tested the link's functionality manually and it works fine. But when I automate and execute through Selenium, the `add new` (it's basically a hypertext link) feature is not visible at all. I tried on multiple browsers. The issue is the same for each browser and throws this error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == .inner>table>tbody>tr>td>a>strong
```

Obviously, because the `add new` link is not present. This happens only when the test is executed through Selenium. It works fine manually.

Comment: ...well it may not be obviously not present... it could be that your CSS Selector is not correct. If you would include the relevant HTML we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: If it is basically a hyperlink, then use linktext instead of CSS selector.

Comment: Addd the HTML code to help finding the issue

Comment: Make your test script to wait till the required element is loaded in the page. Try using webdriver wait.

Comment: I resolved the issue. I guess there was an issue with the WebElement name and I changed it to another name. It worked after that.